# Better way to store game objects?

Tags: arrays, binary, tile

I'm coding tile based 2d game.

I store the *first layer*(water,grass,dirt,etc...) as 2d array of integers, where each value[x,y] represents particular tile.

And it's okay, but I need also to store the *second layer*(objects) somehow. It is impossible to use 2d array as for tiles, because each object has some **additional** data. For example: chest object contains data about items in it and their number, oven contains data about fuel and so on...

I prefer to store both layers in RAM permanently, because size of my map is not so big. And I need to save layer1 and layer2 in file. For layer1 I use binary file, it is fast and simple.

So I'm interested, what is the most efficient way to store the layer of objects? (Once again, I want to have it in RAM all the time during game operation, and also save it binary file)
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't specified a language, but assuming it allows OOP, you could create a class for each item in the second layer, then use a 2D array of those objects.

Comment: I'm using C++, Yes that's good idea, but how to store it in file? Also, I thik it takes a lot of memory, because tree and stone objects have no additional information, and chest has much more such data than oven. And also most of such objects in 2d array just NULL, because I don't have object at every tile.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way is to store an array of objects like this:

1. Amount of objects
2. Object data

Each object data can be variable length record like this:

1. Object type ( tree, enemy, trunk e.t.c.)
2. x, y coords
3. additional data depending on object type ( height for tree, attack and defence for an enemy, contents of the trunk again as an array e.t.c)

In this way you can read/write additional object data depending on object type.

Comment: But how can I store such record in RAM? Of course, I can store objects in file as list, but I have no idea how to use it from RAM. What kind of structure do you recommend?

Comment: I suppose it's better to store second layer as two dimensional array too. Thus you can easily answer to question "what is at coords x,y?"

Make an interface for the object with abstract function "GetType()" and inherit all objects from this interface. Override "GetType()" in every object to return type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I can use 2d array of variable length arrays to store it. And use some divisor to store it in a binary file, i.e:

http://rghost.ru/8DZHjSm5M.view
(image here)

And we have N*N such records in file.

So arr[0][0][0] gives me a type of object, arr[0][0][n] gives me some additional information. Just need to code some parser.

What do you think?